# Get slider to display months instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a `html` slider to output the months. I made a slider with a max value of 12, starting at 1.

My `html`  instead of the numberscode for the rangeslider is:

```
<label id="labelslider" for="slider">Bepaal de forecast periode:</label> <!-- Range -->
<input type="range" id="slider" min="1" max="12" value="1" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" />
<output for="slider" id="range">0</output>
```

My `javascript` code is:

```
function outputUpdate(vol) {
    //document.querySelector('#range').value = vol;
    switch(document.querySelector('#range').value) {
        case "1":
            "Januari" = vol;
        break;
        case "2":
            "Februari" = vol;
        break;
        case "3":
            "Maart" = vol;
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried to incorporate the switch functions to dislpay the months, but i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes.

1. You should have the value in the RHS of the operator.
2. You should use the `#slider`'s value to switch.
3. You don't need to pass any values to the function.

**Working Snippet**

```js
function outputUpdate() {
  var vol = "";
  switch(document.querySelector('#slider').value) {
    case "1":
      vol = "Januari";
      break;
    case "2":
      vol = "Februari";
      break;
    case "3":
      vol = "Maart";
      break;
  }
  document.querySelector('#range').innerHTML = vol;
}
```

```html
<label id="labelslider" for="slider">Bepaal de forecast periode:</label>
<input type="range" id="slider" min="1" max="12" value="1" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" />
<output for="slider" id="range">0</output>
```

A better version is to use arrays:

```js
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
function outputUpdate() {
  document.querySelector('#range').innerHTML = months[document.querySelector('#slider').value - 1];
}
```

```html
<label id="labelslider" for="slider">Bepaal de forecast periode:</label>
<input type="range" id="slider" min="1" max="12" value="1" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" />
<output for="slider" id="range">January</output>
```

Comment: `the value in the RHS of the operator`: It's unclear to me, what is that?

Comment: @GG. `"Januari" = vol;` is wrong. `vol = "Januari";` is right.

Comment: Ok I see. But what does "RHS" stand for?

Comment: @GG. Ah... *Right Hand Side*! Google duh! :P

Comment: Many thanks! Is it also possible to have the months in the center, under the slider?

Comment: @CostCare Yes, just use a `display: inline-block` and give `text-align: center`.

Comment: @CostCare `#slider,
#range {display: block; width: 200px; text-align: center;}` - This is what you need to put in your CSS. `:)` Enjoy.